# PayPal does not show order summary-Omnipay

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5.1, omnipay

[image: Order_summary_image]

I have a function for Paypal redirection for that I pass some values in params..

It only pass the `Description` field doesn't shows the amount to be paid,and rest of my order summaries..

Here is my function

```
public function postPayment() 
{   
    $hot_id     = \Session::get('hot_id');
    $user_id    = \Session::get('uid');
    $check_in   = \Session::get('check_in');
    $check_out  = \Session::get('check_out');
    $mem_count  = \Session::get('mem_count');
    $rm_no      = \Session::get('rm_no');

    $check_in   = strtotime($check_in);
    $check_in   = date('Y-m-d',$check_in);

    $check_out  = strtotime($check_out);
    $check_out  = date('Y-m-d',$check_out);

    $datediff   = strtotime($check_out) - strtotime($check_in);
    $diff       = floor($datediff/(86400));

    $room_prize = \DB::select("SELECT `room_prize` FROM `abserve_hotel_rooms` WHERE `room_id` = ".$_POST['room_id']);
    $arr = array();
        foreach ($room_prize as $key => $value) {
            $arr[]= (get_object_vars($value));
        }
        $room_prize = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $room_prize[]=($value['room_prize']);
        }
    if($rm_no == 1)
    {
        $room_prize = (int) $room_prize[0] * (int) $diff;
    }
    else
    {
        $room_prize = (int) $room_prize[0] * (int) $diff * (int) $rm_no;
    }

    $room_prize = number_format((float)$room_prize, 2, '.', '');
    $room_id    = $_POST['room_id'];

    $today      = new DateTime();
    $created_at = $today->format('Y-m-d');

    $values = array('user_id' => $user_id,'hotel_id' => $hot_id,'room_id'=>$room_id,'room_prize'=>$room_prize,'check_in'=>$check_in,'check_out'=>$check_out,'created_at'=>$created_at);

    \DB::table('abserve_orders')->insert($values);

    $order_id = DB::select("SELECT `id` FROM `abserve_orders` WHERE `room_id` = ".$_POST['room_id']." AND `user_id` = ".$user_id);
    $arr = array();
        foreach ($order_id as $key => $value) {
            $arr[]= (get_object_vars($value));
        }
        $order_id = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $order_id[]=($value['id']);
        }
        $order_id = $order_id[0];

        $params = array(
                'cancelUrl'     => url().'/cancel_order',
                'returnUrl'     => url().'/payment_success', 
                'name'          => 'new order',
                'description'   => 'description1', 
                'amount'        => $room_prize,
                'currency'      => 'USD',
                'hot_id'        => $hot_id,
                'room_id'       => $room_id,
                'user_id'       => $user_id,
                'check_in'      => $check_in,
                'check_out'     => $check_out,
                'order_id'      => $order_id,
                'nights'        => $diff,
        );
        // print_r($params);exit;
        \Session::put('params', $params);
        \Session::save();  

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');

        $gateway->setUsername('googley555_api1.yahoo.com');
        $gateway->setPassword('3EQ6S6PB68A52JKZ');
        $gateway->setSignature('AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AHaEiWOLAf5jQQ3-A9hLlhypSz9h');
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

    $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->send();

        if ($response->isSuccessful()) {

            // payment was successful: update database
            print_r($response);

    } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {

            // redirect to offsite payment gateway
            $response->redirect();

    } else {

          // payment failed: display message to customer
          echo $response->getMessage();

    }
}
```

I don't know what are missing in it..

Someone please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass in arbitrary parameters such as hot_id, room_id, etc to PayPal (or omnipay) because it won't know what to do with them.  PayPal is only intended to take certain parameters and the ones that PayPal does not take are ignored by Omnipay.

You may have to provide all of these extra parameters as part of the description parameter, which PayPal does understand.

Ideally these should be displayed by your application in some kind of useful format to the user before redirecting the user to the PayPal checkout page.